# Best practise for apache shiro security in async (batch) processing

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler, batch-processing, shiro

Suppose I have a web application which uses Apache Shiro for authentication (LDAP) and authorization (DB). Everything's fine.
Now I want the web user to schedule some time consuming tasks using Quartz.
Shall the permission be checked only at task creation or as well at task execution?
I would say both but then it means that the task should authenticate and get authorized again.
Problem is that I might know the username but not the password...

Bypassing the authentication I guess it would be wrong.
I might use a default user for batch/async processing, but I would miss the last A (Audit).

What other options do I have?
Would the rememberMe feature help me?

Thank you,
Mats